# Stirling's approximation for Gamma function

Tags: functions, inequality

Is that true for any $x>0$, the gamma function

$
\Gamma(x)\le x^x?
$

I know this is true for integers but am not sure for any $x>0$.

Comment: It's not true, $\Gamma$ has a pole at $0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \Gamma(x) = +\infty$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^x = 1$. Since $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$, perhaps you wanted to ask whether $\Gamma(x+1) \leqslant x^x$ for all $x > 0$?

Comment: The idea of trying to compare $\Gamma(x+1)=\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t} dt$ and $x^x=\int_0^\infty x^x e^{-t} dt$ comes to mind. That is, your inequality (corrected in accordance with Daniel Fischer's point) would be equivalent to $\int_0^\infty (t^x-x^x) e^{-t} dt \leq 0$ for $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, just a strategy: can you use the fact that the inequality holds for integers to show that it holds for rationals? Because then continuity would do it, right?

Comment: No, actually, that wouldn't be enough by itself. You need to know something about how the Gamma function behaves at values between positive integers. This might be possible to assess by just looking at the interval $[1,2]$, in view of the familiar functional equation for the Gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  Consider, for example, $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi>1>(1/2)^{1/2}$.

However, this is true whenever $x>1$ since

$$\Gamma(x)<\Gamma(1+x)=\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-t}dt\le\int_0^\infty x^xe^{-t}dt=x^x$$

Comment: Why is $\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\,dt \leqslant \int_0^\infty x^x e^{-t}\,dt$? I don't think that's obvious.

Comment: I agree with @DanielFischer : the left integrand is smaller on $[0,x)$ and bigger on $(x,\infty)$...

Comment: It seems I only need the case when $x\ge1$, this paper maybe useful http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/264_06_JIPAM/264_06.pdf

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments.  I'll get to fixing this up once I have the time.